# Método de defuzzificación

Tags: python-3.7

¿cómo puedo modificar el método de defuzzificación en este ejemplo: https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/auto_examples/plot_tipping_problem_newapi.html?
Gracias

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta no muestra claramente lo que has intentado (si acaso has intentado algo). Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta añadiendo lo que hayas intentado, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. De lo contrario seguramente tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Esta pregunta está bastante fuzzy. ¿Podrías aclarar lo que necesitas hacer?

Comment: Hay infinitas formas de modificar ese código, si bien la mayoría de ellas producirán errores sintácticos, o en tiempo de ejecución. Una fracción mínima harán algo, pero seguramente distinto de lo que tu querrías. Por cierto ¿qué es?

Comment: Buenas adjunto el código: https://github.com/elcesi/Predictivo_fuzzylogic/blob/master/Modelo_predictivo_duraciones_Fuzzy_logic.ipynb. Se trata de un predicitivo de duraciones de patologias en función de dos variables V1 y V2. El consecuente V3 es la duración predicha. Lo que quiero es saebr cómo modificar el método de defuzzificatión ya que por defecto en el código está el método "centroid". Espero haber aclarado más. Gracias